# Is it possible that running Ubuntu on my Windows computer from a USB stick could cause damage to my computer?

Tags: usb, windows

I was just wondering - can any harm come to my computer from running Ubuntu from a USB stick? Obviously this excludes things like an infected Ubuntu installation or trojans hidden on the USB. Assuming that the install was perfectly safe and clean, could any damage result from such? If so, is the probability of such damage worth worrying about?

I honestly am very unfamiliar with this kind of thing, despite being reasonably literate at computer usage, and would appreciate any clearing-up of the matter.

Comment: possibly relevant: [Chances of Ubuntu breaking my PC?](/q/532467/175814); I'd say the same applies to running Ubuntu as a live system from a USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, nothing will be modified on the Windows side unless you as a user perform an action to do so.

Comment: Although correct, I think the answer could extend a bit: you *can* destroy everything from your Ubuntu live session with a couple of commands well (eh) chosen. But no, normally no harm is done. On the other side, one should ever *ever* have a recent backup. Whatever you're doing or not doing; disks *do* die.

Answer (score 0):

There's no stupid questions. We've all been there.. Well.. I'm still "there".

Anyway, there's nothing from a Ubuntu flashed USB that can harm your computer in any way. (At least what I know of and I've flashed a bunch of computers).

If you haven't backed up all your files all ready, I strongly recommend it before you start experiment with things you clearly lack experience from.

Good luck!

Comment: I would have added: it is *extremely* hard damaging your computer with Ubuntu boot from USB, unless you actually dig into your Windows files and manually delete them... ;)